# isset function doesn't work on my form and form is nod getting submitted

Tags: php, forms, isset

I am submitting form to page and checking if submit button value InsertMe isset but non of the code inside is executed

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['InsertMe'])){

//code to execute
echo "Test";

}
?>
```

and insert buttons looks like that

```
<input style="float:right;" name="InsertMe" id="InsertMe" type="submit" class="rectangular-button" value="Add User" />
```

Comment: Is your form using POST?

Comment: Can you try `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`?

Comment: Add a `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of the file

Comment: not sure if it's related but why do you have the type="submit" on the input? did you try to update your form in order to have one input named InsertMe carrying your value, and a button/anchor submitting the form, having the Type=submit ?

Comment: Use isset on the submit button

Comment: can you post the code for form

Comment: Maybe used `GET` method!

Comment: why do you need the value of the submit button?

Comment: @yonessafari And pass the passwords through the URL? wat

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_POST['InsertMe']) || empty($_POST['InsertMe'])) {

// error message here

} else {

// What you want to do if not empty and is set.

}
```

This code will check if the variables is set and if if it's empty.

"||" is the PHP operator to check or. So in this case it's checking if it's set OR empty.

Comment: @Script47 - you're missing a closing bracket after the isset function call.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the form tag set to post.

```
<form method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting Id I think we should be use name tag parameters in isset()

Comment: name and id have the same name, why do you think that should be wrong?